# PHP: Global var not being picked up inside a function

Tags: php, variables, global-variables

This is blowing my mind...

I've got a standalone PHP file, and a simple function with a global var.

```
<?php
    $var = 4;

    function echoVar()
    {
        echo $var; 
    }

    echoVar();
?>
```

When I call `echoVar()` nothing is returned... However if I place the `$var` inside the function it will return 4.

What's going on here? Shouldn't `$var` be global in this case?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: You seem to be confusing `PHP` with how scope works in some other languages (js for example). Please [refer to the manual to see how scope works in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Try like this: function echoVar()
    {
        global $var; 

        echo  $var; 
    }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a variable is set outside of a function, it's not visible inside that function. To access it, you must declare it global with the `global` keyword. This is called a *scope*.

```
<?php

$var = 4;

function echoVar() {
    global $var;

    echo $var;
}

echoVar();
```

**Note:** This is generally considered bad practice. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why) for more information.

A good alternative would be to pass in the variable as an argument:

```
<?php

$var = 4;

function echoVar($var) {
    echo $var;
}

echoVar($var);
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me understand it much better. I come from JS world so this seemed very strange indeed!

Answer (score 3):

Lots of options here... like

```
<?php
    $var = 4;

    function echoVar($var)
    {
        echo $var; 
    }

    echoVar($var);
?>
```

or

```
<?php
    $var = 4;

    function echoVar()
    {
        global $var;
        echo $var; 
    }

    echoVar();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks.. fixed. As for bad practice, it's just another example on how to accomplish this. The code is there to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can either have $var as an argument, like this:

$var = 4;

```
function echoVar($var)
{
    echo $var; 
}

echoVar($var);
```

or use global, like this:

```
$var = 4;

function echoVar()
{

    global $var;
    echo $var; 
}

echoVar();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call any function it's create local variable so you have to pass argument in calling function part.

```
    $var = 4;

    function echoVar($var)
    {
        echo $var; 
    }

    echoVar($var);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just going to clarify since everyone seems to be posting mostly rubbish.

- Do not use `global $var;`
- Do not echo out inside of a function
- Output from a function does not need to be assigned to a variable before being echo'd

This is how it "should" be done.

```
<?php
    $var = 4;  //set initial input var this is external to the function

    function echoVar($internalvar) {  /*notice were accepting $var as $internalvar I'm doing this to clarify the different variables so you don't end up getting confused with scope  $internalvar is local to the function only and not accessible externally*/
        return $internalvar; //now we pass the function internal var back out to the main code we do this with return you should never echo out your output inside the function
    }

    echo echoVar($var);  //call function and pass $var in as an arguement
?>
```